# How can I receive the intial TLS SNI domain name, and delay providing a certificate to the client for a few seconds

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, sni

When an incoming connection for https://myservice.example.com is received (for the first time) I would like to be able to take some action (based on the SNI name) before giving a valid certificate to the https server to use for that connection.  I do not want to break the connection, just delay it for a few seconds.

The action I want to take, on the first connection of an unknown SNI name, is to get a certificate from Let's Encrypt for that (sub)domain.  This will take a few seconds, but usually less than a minute, and and will only happen on the first connection.

I want to be able to tell users to set a CNAME or A record for `myservicename.theirdomain.com` (pointing to my server) and for my server to get a Let's Encrypt cert for `myservicename.theirdomain.com` on the first attempted connection, with no need for sign-up, etc.

If they first connect using http, there is no issue, as the server can get a certificate and *then* redirect them to https.  It's the cases where they go to https first, that I'm trying to cover.  These cases are not getting less common, as browsers ramp-up security and they become littered with permanent redirects to https.

How do I get nodejs to call me as soon as an https connection's SNI name is available, and let me set the certificate before calling it back?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good idea in the first place. One could just setup a CNAME for `*.example.com` pointing to your site and then mass enumerating subdomains so that you are busy getting new certificates from Let's Encypt until rate limiting hits you.

Comment: You would need to tie at a quite low level with your webserver to be able to do anything like that. It is possible for example in nginx with LUA code. It may be too costly to create the certificate then at least synchronously, and you may want to cache it after creation. Timeouts, especially in web, are short, I am not sure the client will wait 1 minute for TLS to start...

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks, but I doubt many users would want to turn over their whole domain to my service.  Also, iirc you cannot enumerate DNSSEC domains.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Yes, I am asking for how to tie into the NodeJS HTTPS server at a low level.  I have assumed that it would be more flexible than Nginx or Apache, though I will look into your suggestion of Nginx with LUA code.

Comment: @fadedbee: *"... I doubt many users would want to turn over their whole domain to my service."* - this is not about some friendly customer but about an attacker who wants to harm your service. The attacker can simply point `*.subdomain.attacker.site` to your site. Or just create SSL handshakes with lots of different SNI information without even doing some CNAME configuration. The problem is you believe that every request you get is valid and innocent and that you can blindly act on it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Good point.